# jobs.batch is forbidden: User ' '"system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default"

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I am using [Kubernetes javascript client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) with, **in-cluster configurations** to interact with the cluster.

I am trying to get the list of jobs

app.js(Node)

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  k8sApi2
    .listNamespacedJob("default")
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.body);
      res.send(res.body);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

But this is the log of the pod I am getting.

[image: Log]

Here are my deployment

[image: Deployment]

Service

[image: Service]

Also, I created a role and a role binding but still, I have no idea what makes this issue.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: node-apis
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: node-apis
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - "apps"
      - "batch"
    resources:
      - endpoints
      - deployments
      - pods
      - jobs
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
      - create
      - delete
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: node-apis
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: node-apis
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: node-apis
```

I am new to Kubernetes, any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the service account by specifying it in the spec section of the pod.Since you are not doing that it's using the `default` service account which does not have Role and RoleBinding permitting the operation, leading to `forbidden` error.

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: node-apis
  containers:
  ...
```

Alternatively you can give permission to the `default` service account in the RoleBinding

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: node-apis
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: node-apis
```

Comment: That not really works for me, do you have any idea?
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/issues/654